# Is there a server-side JavaScript framework (node.js) that produces html pages without using a template engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been having a bit of a look at node.js but I haven't actually done anything with it yet. From what I can see node.js is roughly the same as the Servlet api from java.

My question is: Are there there any server-side JavaScript frameworks that produce the html page to send to the client but which don't take a template engine approach?

I'm thinking along the lines of something like Apache Wicket, or Vaadin in the Java world.

I'm thinking of more of a multi-page approach rather than a single-page is the app that something like Dojo(?) would take (but I don't know anything about that either).

I'm not afraid of learning template languages (I know Velocity and Free Marker) but I like the cleaner approach that a server-side framework brings.

Comment: you can hook up a web server to node and serve pages through that. fun to play around with

Comment: @johnp: do you have any examples of that? I'm interested in playing around with that

Comment: This video covers it about half way in. He talks about plugging in an http server - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I

Answer (score 2):

You could write it all in html and then use some sort of client side lib (say jQuery) server-side with [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a component-based template engine (JSF, Wicket, Vaadin). As far as I know, no such engines exist for NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything like that exists yet. That said, maybe you could begin writing it? Maybe my templating project https://github.com/thejh/node-vacuum would help you with that - you can easily use JS functions as templates, and it takes care of executing all functions on one level at the same time, bringing fragments in the right order and streaming partial responses while your db query or whatever is still pending.